Microsoft Teams Graph API Get List of Webinars
I'm using the new MS Teams Graph API to get a list of webinars: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/virtualeventsroot-list-webinars?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

it returns a list of 100 even though there is a total of 153 of webinars.
Question: how can I order them by newest so that I can get the newest ones on top? OR get page num 2?
FYI: Cancelling the webinar does not remove it, simply changes that status to 'Cancelled' and they still show up in the list

Maybe a little late, but you have to use the OdataNextLink attribute of the VirtualEventRegistrationCollectionResponse class to get the next page of registrants. An example of that would look like this
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<VirtualEventRegistration> GetAllAsync(this RegistrationsRequestBuilder requestBuilder)
{
    var nextLink = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        VirtualEventRegistrationCollectionResponse response;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextLink))
            response = await requestBuilder.GetAsync();
        else
            response = await requestBuilder.WithUrl(nextLink).GetAsync();

        nextLink = response.OdataNextLink;

        foreach (var registration in response.Value)
        {
            yield return registration;
        }
    }
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextLink));
}

